# SQL : how to get this type of result set in sql for the provided data

Tags: sql

I've two columns with multiple rows. Where my second column will have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I need the result based on my second column.

My result hierarchy is 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5... I want the relevant numbers to be displayed based on the hierarchy, but a number falling in previous hierarchy **should not be considered** for all the next hierarchies; e.g., 2589 should be there for 1 but not for 3, 2522 should be there for 2 but not for 5.

```
+---------+--------+
|  First  | Second |
+---------+--------+
|    0256 |      1 |
|    5264 |      4 |
|    2589 |      3 |
|    2522 |      2 |
|    2489 |      1 |
|    2589 |      1 |
|    2522 |      5 |
|    5264 |      2 |
|    1145 |      5 |
|    8884 |      4 |
+---------+--------+
```

The needed result should be

```
+-------+---------+
|  Hier | Number  |
+-------+---------+
|     1 |    2489 |
|     1 |     258 |
|     1 |     025 |
|     2 |    2522 |
|     2 |    5264 |
|     4 |    8884 |
|     5 |    1145 |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: sorry the table is messed

Comment: please write those as columns and help in deriving the result

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post - may be helpful for you  https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/04/building-flat-hierarchy-out-of.html?view=magazine

Comment: You are just trying to `group by` the column `First`, and get the `min` of the column `Second`. Something like `select first as Number, min(second) as Hier from table1 group by first` should do.

Answer (score 0):

This query will solve the problem. I took the liberty to name the first table you describe in the example as table1

```
WITH temp_tbl AS
(
    SELECT
        first,
        MIN(second)
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY first
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.second as Hier,
    t1.first as Number
FROM table1 t1
JOIN temp_tbl t2
    ON t1.first = t2.first AND t1.second = t2.second
ORDER BY t1.second, t1.first
```

Edit: as it was point out in the comments the first select of the query will do the trick. If you want it ordered depending on the db engine you may have to nest the select in another one.

Comment: Why do you need the second part? The simple `select first as Number, min(second) as Hier from table1 group by first` will do.